# SQL filter in group

Tags: sql, group-by

I have a database with one Table:

```
+-------+------+--+
| Col1  | Col2 |  |
+-------+------+--+
| Auto  | alt  |  |
| Auto  | alt  |  |
| Auto  | neu  |  |
| Haus  | alt  |  |
| Haus  | alt  |  |
| Stuhl | neu  |  |
+-------+------+--+
```

Now I want to get all groups from Col1 with more than one repition like Auto and Haus. I did that with:

```
SELECT talbe1.Col1, talbe1.Col2
FROM table1
WHERE talbe1.Col1 In (SELECT Col1 FROM talbe1.Col1 As Tmp GROUP BY Col1 HAVING Count(Col1)>1)
ORDER BY talbe1.Col1;
```

Additionally I now want these groups only when the values in Col2 are NOT all the same like in Auto. The result would look like this:

```
+------+------+--+
| Col1 | Col2 |  |
+------+------+--+
| Auto | alt  |  |
| Auto | alt  |  |
| Auto | neu  |  |
+------+------+--+
```

Can someone help me how to do that in SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t3.Col1,t3.Col2
FROM table1 t3
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT t1.Col1
FROM (SELECT Col1,Col2,COUNT(*) AS cn FROM table1 GROUP BY Col1,Col2) t1
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT Col1,COUNT(*) AS cn
FROM table1
GROUP BY Col1
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) t2
ON t1.Col1=t2.Col1 AND t1.cn != t2.cn
GROUP BY t1.Col1
) t4
ON t3.col1=t4.col1
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Col1    Col2
Auto    alt
Auto    alt
Auto    neu
```

**Demo**

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/24b3ec/33

Comment: Thats not working. It just gives me the rows for both columns having repitions. But I want to get the groups from Col1 where NOT all values in Col2 are the same

Comment: Check my answer now @otto.kranz

Answer (score 1):

You could use `exists`

```
select * from table t
where exists (select 1 from table 
              where Col1 = t.Col1 
              group by Col1 
              having count(distinct Col2) > 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery to find the values in the column that satisfy the condition, and then get the rest of the necessary information:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (col1 VARCHAR(max), col2 VARCHAR(max)) 

INSERT INTO @Table (col1, col2)
values
('Auto', 'alt'),
('Auto', 'alt'),
('Auto', 'neu'),
('Haus', 'alt'),
('Haus', 'alt'),
('Stuhl', 'neu')

SELECT *
FROM @Table
WHERE col1 IN (
    SELECT col1
    FROM @Table
    GROUP BY col1
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 
    AND COUNT(DISTINCT col2) > 1 
)
```

Where is the condition:

```
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Find all duplicate values in column `col1`

And this condition:

```
AND COUNT(DISTINCT col2) > 1
```

Find those records in which column `col2` has non-unique values